# Getting Error in to retrieve User's Email ID While FBSDKGraphRequest in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

In My app I'm Trying to integrate the Facebook With Login By Using FaceBookSDK V4,Here i Successfully logged In and trying to Get the User's Email i'm Getting Error.In viewDidLoad i put theFollowing Code:

```
  FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
        loginButton.frame=CGRectMake(50,100,500,50);
        loginButton.readPermissions=@[@"email"];
        [self.view addSubview:loginButton];


        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
             }
             else{
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];
```

Finally i'm Getting the Following Error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x15d9b570 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Parse, you need to switch out the ParseFacebookUtils with ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and update accordingly. Regular ParseFacebookUtils does not work with FB SDK V4, and you end up with very cryptic errors and random run-time failures (such as the elusive error code 8).